# How to manage what OVI maps are installed on my Nokia mobile?

Tags: nokia-pc-suite

#### Question

> How can I display and manage what maps are installed for OVI Maps to use?

---

#### Loooong story

I begrudgingly installed the Nokia Ovi Suite on my computer to download maps to our new Nokia mobile. Downloading and installing maps and voices for Italy was quick and painless.

After a while, I notice an entry saying "Updated maps avialable." Confused -- I just installed them -- I click on the text, hoping for an explaination. An "updating maps in progress" screen appears:

[image: The 'Updated maps available' screen.]

Don't squint, here's the small print:

> #### Updating maps in progress...
>
> During the updating, all existing maps and voice guidance files are deleted and new ones are automatically transferred to your device. This may take some time.
>
> #### Do not disconnect your device.

Gee, that's a brutal way to update. A scaring long deletion process after, it started updating maps. For *Germany*.

I didn't install Germany maps, nor I need them. I *guess* these maps came preinstalled. How can I be sure? How can I delete them?

How can I display and manage maps what maps are installed for OVI Maps to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *so* blind I'd rather delete this question in shame. However, I'll keep it for others in case they do not notice the **"On your device"** section on the screen.

Comment: Well, I guess that posting it, and seeing the screenshot there helped ;) Thank you for not deleting, it can always be useful to someone else.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me where is the on your device section? I can't find it.
Also, you can select which maps to install using the selection or the right. You have continents and when you select continent, you get country list. You can then select individual maps to install.

Comment: @Andreja right above the phone thumbnail. My problem wasn't adding, but removing. Unfortunately, the only option you have is "DELETE ALL"